# Gem procress as Terminal title

Tags: macos, command-line, osx-snow-leopard, terminal

I run Snow Leopard and I use the Terminal for Rails development.

If you do web development, you would realize that regardless of the gems being run, your terminal name switches from bash to ruby.

Is there a way to have the gem name listed as the Terminal name?

A good "test case" would be to run the spork DRB server and expect "spork" as the terminal title as opposed to "ruby".